Find inverse Hankel transform $\mathcal{H}_{v - \frac{1}{2}} \left( f(r) \right) = J_{v - \frac{1}{2}} (s) \frac{1}{(1+a^2 s^2)^{v + \frac{1}{2}}}$
Suppose that
$$\mathcal{H}_{v - \frac{1}{2}} \left(  f \right)(s) = J_{v - \frac{1}{2}} (s)  \frac{1}{(1+a^2 s^2)^{v + \frac{1}{2}}}$$
where $\mathcal{H}_{v - \frac{1}{2}} \, \left(  f \right)(s)$ is the Hankel transform of a function $f$ and $J_{v - \frac{1}{2}} (s)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind.
Our goal is to find the inverse Hankel transform. That is, find $f$.
It tried applying the Binomial theorem on the rational term. However, there are several difficulties with this approach. For example, $v$ is not an integer the sum becomes infinite.
